# How to fix the issue:Your PHP installation appears to be missing the MySQL extension

Tags: php, mysql

Environment:os and apache and php and mariadb version.

```
uname -a
Linux MiWiFi-R3-srv 4.9.0-11-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 4.9.189-3+deb9u2 (2019-11-11) x86_64 GNU/Linux

sudo apachectl -v
Server version: Apache/2.4.25 (Debian)
Server built:   2019-10-13T15:43:54

php -v
PHP 7.0.33-0+deb9u6 (cli) (built: Oct 24 2019 18:50:20) ( NTS )
Copyright (c) 1997-2017 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.0.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2017 Zend Technologies
    with Zend OPcache v7.0.33-0+deb9u6, Copyright (c) 1999-2017, by Zend Technologies
```

Login mariadb with password and input `status`:

```
Server:         MariaDB
Server version:     10.1.41-MariaDB-0+deb9u1 Debian 9.9
```

Check php-mysql:

```
sudo dpkg -l php-mysql
Desired=Unknown/Install/Remove/Purge/Hold
| Status=Not/Inst/Conf-files/Unpacked/halF-conf/Half-inst/trig-aWait/Trig-pend
|/ Err?=(none)/Reinst-required (Status,Err: uppercase=bad)
||/ Name           Version      Architecture Description
+++-==============-============-============-=================================
ii  php-mysql      1:7.0+49     all          MySQL module for PHP [default]
```

Get the mysql.so library:

```
sudo find  /  -name  "*mysql.so"
/usr/lib/php/20151012/pdo_mysql.so
```

Chekc all modules which contain mysql:

```
php -m |grep  mysql
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib/php/20151012/php_pdo_mysql.so' - /usr/lib/php/20151012/php_pdo_mysql.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0
mysqli
mysqlnd
pdo_mysql


sudo vim  /etc/php/7.0/fpm/php.ini
```

Rewrite

```
; ... or under UNIX:
;
;extension=mysql.so
```

as

```
extension=mysqli.so
```

or

```
extension=mysqlnd.so
```

or

```
extension=pdo_mysql.so
```

Restart apache2 and mariadb database,the issue remains ,none of the three format can work,how to fix then?

Comment: `pdo_mysql` is not the same as `mysql.so`. The old `mysql` extension was removed in PHP 7.0. The supported extension is now `mysqli`. Then it depends on what the software is expecting to find - if it needs the old `mysql` library, then you're going to have to use a shim or an older PHP version.

Comment: Use `php -m` to check whether `pdo_mysql` exists.

Comment: Putting a bounty on this won't change the fact that this is a bad question, instead it will just attract bad answers. Presumably, you have not listened to the advice from @MatsLindh?

Comment: What is the application that you are trying to install?

Comment: If no answer satisfactorily answers your question, please clarify what additional information it is that you are looking for.

Answer (score 11):

`pdo_mysql` is not the same as `mysql.so`. The old `mysql` extension was removed in PHP 7.0. The supported extension is now only `mysqli`.

From there on it depends on what the software is expecting to find - if it needs the old `mysql` library, then you're going to have to use a shim or an older PHP version (i.e. anything before PHP 7, such as PHP 5.6).

You [can use the `php7-mysql-shim` library](https://github.com/dshafik/php7-mysql-shim) or [the `mysql-shim` library](https://github.com/dotpointer/mysql-shim) (be aware, this might incur a small performance penalty) to make a transparent mapping available that dispatches any calls to the old `mysql` library to the still supported `mysqli` library. As long as you've installed `php7-mysql-shim` through composer and your project uses composer, it should be loaded automagically.

A third option is to run the original code [through the `mysql-to-mysqli` rector configuration](https://github.com/rectorphp/rector/blob/main/docs/rector_rules_overview.md#mysqltomysqli), but if this is not your own code, that will be hard to maintain in the future.

The `.so` file that can't be loaded might be because of permission issue. Make sure to `ls -al` that file and correct any ownership or permission issues (`chmod og+r <filename>`, probably).

Answer (score 0):

Remove php and related packages.

```
sudo apt-get autoremove php7*
sudo find /etc -name "*php*" |xargs  rm -rf 
sudo apt purge `dpkg -l | grep php| awk '{print $2}' |tr "\n" " "`
```

Check.

```
dpkg -l | grep php7.0
```

Install.

```
sudo apt-get install php php-mysql
```

At last my issue solved.

Answer (score 0):

MatsLindh is right, mysql is deprecated from php 7, it seems that you have deployed old php5 code on the server that is why you received this error, now you can do two things

- either install php5.6 and select the version for that website folder depending on which hosting you have and restart the server
- or you can upgrade the code to php 7+ either yourself or by using tools which I do not know if it works perfectly, recently I came across this 
  [Rector Tool for upgrading php legacy code](https://github.com/rectorphp/rector)

We were down the same path in previous months and and we updated mysql code to mysqli and also updated the classes declarations and added the necessary checking, fixed the error handling and we were able to run the legacy app on the php 7 successfully. 
Sometime due to complicated development, it is not possible to upgrade in an instant and it is also not possible to start from the scratch either because of the business logic introduced over the years so changes can only be introduced with baby steps, I can say this because we handle our high traffic ecommerce site.

Answer (score 0):

As others have stated, though without a source, the mysql extension (ext/mysql) was [deprecated in 5.5](https://www.php.net/manual/en/migration55.deprecated.php) (per [RFC: ext/mysql deprecation](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation)) and [removed in 7.0](https://www.php.net/manual/en/migration70.removed-exts-sapis.php) (per [RFC: Remove deprecated functionality in PHP 7](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/remove_deprecated_functionality_in_php7)).

([This is the git commit](https://github.com/php/php-src/commit/fd1578c196575c7e120a84ee030bb87c14a199b0) that actually removed ext/mysql from PHP, as linked to from the removal RFC - this link was added by the RFC author [[nikic]](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/remove_deprecated_functionality_in_php7?do=revisions))

This is also mentioned all throughout the [ext/mysql manual](https://www.php.net/manual/en/intro.mysql.php) on php.net, though it doesn't link to any other notes concerning the deprecation and subsequent removal.

---

If you view the [backwards-incompatible changes page for 7.0](https://www.php.net/manual/en/migration70.incompatible.php) then it further mentions that all mysql extension functions were removed, and [provides a link](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php) to help in choosing a new MySQL API. This provides the support and path necessary for moving on from ext/mysql.

Answer (score 0):

Avoid using a ***quick fix*** that will make your application support the old `php-mysql` driver. There is a reason that it was removed from `php`.

You can use the successor of `php-mysql` which is the `MySQLi` driver, the name `MySQLi` actually means `MySQL-improved`and as you can understand is an improved version of the `MySQL` driver that gives the developer more benefits.

You may also use the PHP Data Objects (PDO), an extension that defines a lightweight, consistent interface for accessing databases (*MySQL* is one of them) in `PHP`.

This would mean that you would have to re-write pieces of code related with database handled information. If you wrote a class for it then you only need to re-write that class only. If all the `MySQL` related functions are written in all your application then you have a lot of work.

> ***DO NOT USE THE OLD MySQL EXTENSION OR SOMETHING POINTING THAT BY USING A QUICK FIX***.

Do some further reading of your own to judge for yourself what would be the best practice for this situation, *[MySQLi Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MySQLi#cite_note-overview-1)*, *[Introduction to PDO](https://www.php.net/manual/en/intro.pdo.php)*, *[MySQLi Overview](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.overview.php)*.

Answer (score 0):

The First thing that you need to check for this issue is PHP version compatibility with the existing CMS Version.

In most of the cases the error due to that only.

If you are using the domain hosting and have a various site in that, you can also switch the PHP version in one sub domain only by this Htaccess file.

Like this - FcgidWrapper "/home/httpd/cgi-bin/php53-fcgi-starter.fcgi" .php